# using multiple implementations for a 3rd party library in spring: stuck finding a clean approach

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-ioc

I am implementing a custom authentication provider which has to authenticate and authorize user (through one time token/password). There is a server already in place for this purpose, and we have been provided a client API to use in our application for making calls to this authentication/authorization server.

We are allowed to replicate a test setup of that authentication server in our test environments for commercial reasons, hence we have to somehow mock this client API when we deploy to our environments whereas use an actual impl when we deliver to customer. I am stuck creating a clean way of injecting this client API as a bean to my spring application

the client API provided by them is essentially a single package JAR with a public class (no interfaces) and some public static methods to use, there is no interface I can use to inject this client API or a dummy implementation.

this is what I was planning to do

create an interface

```
public interface ClientAPIWrapper {

}
```

and then inject diff implementations of it

i.e.

```
public class DummyClientApiBean implements ClientAPIWrapper
```

and

```
public class ClientApiBean extends ClientAPI implements ClientAPIWrapper
```

but then I realized injecting as type of this interface will not allow accessing the methods of original client API class

```
@Autowired
private ClientAPIWrapper clientApiBean
```

what I want to achieve is to either use the original Client API class as a bean or a dummy bean returning dummy data transparently to the classes using either of the implementations.

something like

```
public MyAuthenticationProvider

@Autowired
private ClientAPI clientApi
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?  Also, Spring Java Config or XML?

Comment: Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE, XML config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the API consists of nothing but static methods (if I've understood your question correctly).  The cleanest solution (but still ugly) is to write an interface for the API AND a facade class with *non-static* methods that delegates to the real API.  For mocking, create a second implementation of the interface.

Comment: I finally chose to create subclasses for the original API, once calls actual superclass methods, the other overrides methods to send dummy response, now injecting them using @Qualifier annotation.